# query offset countdown by 2 each day?

Tags: wp-query

Everything I've tried has been bust... so I'm here asking for help.

I'm looking for a way to set a defined offset number (say offset=1000) that will count down by 2 and reset when it's reached 0 (if possible).

So day 1=1000 / day 2=998 / day 3=996 / etc...

Any ideas?

I've tinkered using date-based arrays but the issue with that path is that the posts I'm trying to revive weren't made every day.

I can't mass-change the post dates or I would (for SEO reasons).

Comment: OK, so today you want to offset posts by 1000. Tomorrow by 998, and so on. Am I right?

Comment: You are right. That's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be several approaches but here is one, which comes in my mind.

**Steps with code example:**

1. Initially, store the count in Database using [Options API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API) like this:

   ```
   update_option('offset_count', 1000); 

   $current_date = date("d");
   update_option('last_countdown_date', $current_date);
   ```
2. Before querying the post, retrieve both values from DB, like this:

   ```
   $offset_count = get_option( 'offset_count' );
   $last_date    = get_option( 'last_countdown_date' );
   ```
3. Now you just need to compare current date with stored date to make your decision. Code would be:

   ```
   $current_date = date("d");

   if( $last_date != $current_date ){ 

       if( $offset_count >= 2 ){
           $offset_count = $offset_count - 2;
       } else{
           $offset_count = 1000;
       }

       update_option('offset_count', $offset_count); 
       update_option('last_countdown_date', $current_date); 

   }
   ```
4. Now just pass `$offset_count` variable to your query.

It will do the job! :)

Comment: Excellent! Is there a way I can quick test this instead of having to wait for tomorrow?

Comment: @Billy Engler, You can store previous date in first step and it will reduce offset count in step 3 so you'll be able to verify it. And please don't forget to accept the answer!